# how to capture and store clickstream data in flutter mobile applications?

Tags: flutter, clickstream

how to store clickstream data for user in flutter mobile apps and store them in a cloud backend for performing analytics and recommendations. I have looked into azure stream analytics and multiple analytics tools but most of them offer only web based sdk's and nothing specific to mobile app. Looking to capture user interaction with the app in order to improve app experience and suggest relevant products to the users.